# URDF model of ultrasonic sensor

Tags: ros, urdf, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am brand new to URDF/xacro and I am trying to figure out the correct way to model an ultra-sonic sensor in urdf format.

From what I know, the model would have to discretize the data so I'm thinking I want to create an arc composed of n rays in order to model this.

However, i'm not sure how to implement this, or even if this is the best way to go about. If you have any ideas, please let me know.

Thanks,
Max

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49888/urdf-model-of-ultrasonic-sensor/) by [mgoldman](https://answers.ros.org/users/3738/mgoldman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. Perhaps this [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/AddingSensorsToPR2) can help you? I think your main issue will be to find the right plugin for the sensor's controller. In addition, you can try to look for robot URDF model that contains similar sensor.

---

Originally posted by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) with karma: 201 on 2012-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0